# ruby how properly update parent and child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have tree related models:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets
  has_one :kid
  attr_accessor :notify_kid
  after_save :let_the_kid_know

  def let_the_kid_know
    if notify_kid == '1'
       self.kid.does_the_kid_know = true
       self.kid.save
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

```
class Kid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

In my test I try to do something like this:

```
 parent.notify_kid = '1'
 parent.pets.first.name = 'Lollipop'
 parent.save!

 assert_equal true, parent.kid.does_the_kid_know
```

Test fails.
Additionally, the pet item doesn't update either.
In the test, I operate on objects already created in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error here: `def let_the_kid_know:`, it should be `def let_the_kid_know` and another `parent.notife_kid` I guess is `parent.notify_kid`.

If that is not enough to fix you problem please post the error you see in the terminal.